# How are attack bonuses calculated in dnd 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack-roll

I am new to dnd, and all of my other characters were told what the attack bonuses are for their weapons, but now that I am on my own, I need to figure out the attack bonus for the quarterstaff, and how to calculate them in the future. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome! I have voted to close this question because the answer already exists on this site (even if on a slightly different question). Don't worry, it's how the site is supposed to work and you did nothing dire. Also see the [help] and maybe take the [tour] to understand how the site works in general.

Comment: Oh damn, forgot the gold badge, I am new to this, sorry. I'm not totally sure it is a duplicate as the questions are (a little) different. One asks how it is calculated while the other asks where it applies to, but they are similar enough that the other could be edited to "How do I calculate it and where is it applied?" and the answers still answer that.

Comment: Actually, this is a (exact) duplicate of another question, it seems: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72910/43856 - although this one asks "is this right?" the question is the same, just written in a different way.

Comment: Additional to Zachiel's comment: if you feel that the linked Q&A does not solve your problem/your problem is different from the one stated there, you can [edit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/135847/edit) your question and clarify how your problem is different from that. This will throw your question in the reopen queue and, if the community feels they are different, the question will be reopened and probably answered.