# Which modifier shown in the D&D Beyond character sheet do I add to attack rolls with my longbow?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack, attack-roll, character-sheets, dnd-beyond

I'm a little uncertain what to add to my attack rolls.
Can anyone confirm which of the below highlighted modifiers I should be adding to my D20 roll for attack with the longbow? I am proficient in archery. Do I add all three or just some?

[image: Character stats]

Comment: Related: "[How do I figure the dice and bonuses for attack rolls and damage rolls?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72910)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I figure the dice and bonuses for attack rolls and damage rolls?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72910/how-do-i-figure-the-dice-and-bonuses-for-attack-rolls-and-damage-rolls)

Comment: @mullac I'd say these aren't duplicates because this one includes the bonus from the Archery fighting style (as the answers to this question point out). The accepted answer from the other question would not explain at all why, for this question, they add +7 to their attack roll.

Comment: Further to Nathan's point, this question also touches on presentation in _D&D Beyond_, another distinguishing factor from the other question. This is similar/related, but not a duplicate.

Comment: As a side note, you'd probably be better off if you turned those odd numbers into even numbers. Assuming that you're playing a non-variant human, you should be able to drop your Intelligence and Wisdom down a point to increase your Constitution up a point.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The +7 that D&D Beyond shows next to your Longbow attack is what you should add to your attack roll.

D&D Beyond adds the +3 Dexterity modifier that you circled, the +2 Proficiency Bonus that you circled, and an additional +2 (probably from Archery fighting style) to come up with the total +7.

Answer (score 13):

The two upper values you've circled both factor into the lower value that you've circled, which is the correct one.

In general, attack bonus = relevant ability modifier + proficiency bonus (if proficient) + other bonuses (if applicable).

In this case you have a +3 Dex modifier and you're proficient with bows (another +2).  The value you've circled in the "Actions" tab is +7, so you're getting +2 from "other bonuses".  In this case, you've picked "Archery"  as your Fighting Style, which provides the final +2.

Comment: Ok thanks heaps. makes total sense.