# Confusion about the damage modifier

Tags: dnd-5e, damage

I am a bit confused with the D&D 5e Starter Set. I'm fairly new to the game.

In the character sheets, I am confused of what dice I use for damage rolls and what the modifiers are?

Is it the one listed under attacks and spellcasting?

Comment: there I a pretty thorough guide about this topic here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/147187/62885

Comment: Welcome to the site Julie! I've cleaned up your question with an [edit] to make it clearer and easier to read. Feel free to edit it further if you need to.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot ^^ 
And sorry for my written english could've been better ^^