# mechanics of attack and roll damage for hill dwarf figther lvl1

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, attack

STR 13 +1
DEX 14 +2
CON 17 +4
INT 15 +2
WIS 12 +1
CHA 17 +3

So, I attack with one hand Battleaxe 1d8 with dueling fighting style:

1. Attack rolld20 - 16+1 from strength +2 from proficiency with Battleaxe total 19
2. Now roll for damage - 1d8 + 2 damage from dueling style = rolled 3+2 (dueling)

Is this correct? And on the attack roll do I need to add +1 damage from strength ability score modifier?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: As [the linked answer shows](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/72923/22566), yes, you add the +1 (STR) damage to the damage roll

Comment: We've marked your question as a dupe because it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. (If that other question doesn't help you, please clarify for us how and why it doesn't, and we'll see what we need to do to help.)

Comment: Did you make a deliberate decision to arrange your ability scores in that way? Obviously you can do whatever is right for your character, but as a Strength-based fighter, it seems like a slightly strange choice. (Also, today I learned that it's possible to duel with a battleaxe! Somehow I assumed it would be finesse weapons only, but nope...)

Answer (score 3):

#### You've got it.

Attack bonus is {relevant ability modifier} + {proficiency bonus, if proficient with the weapon} plus anything else that says it modifies your attack.

Damage bonus is {relevant ability modifier (with squirrely bits when two-weapon fighting)} plus anything else that says it modifies damage.

For your battleaxe STR is the relevant ability, and as a fighter you're proficient. Check, check!

(Also, your CON most should be +3, not +4. It's given by score - 10, divide by 2, round down, if that helps. Or it may just have been a typo.)

Comment: thank you, I have been reading all the basic rules and i am using charactermancer on rolld20, but it seems that messes up the scores etc...

Comment: @DT8 no problem. I'm particularly sympathetic to these sorts of questions as, out of the [~ten editions of D&D](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/13229/23970), basically none of them have ever done a good job of *teaching* the game. (Mentzer's the exception, in my book.) I don't know anything about charactermancer, but I'm sure some of the regulars in [chat] do in case you run up against any other problems. Happy gaming!

Comment: Since you got an answer in, it may be good to cover the misconceptions on modifiers they have for CON.

Comment: Good point. Hadn't even noticed!

Comment: thanks guys for helping, i am new to the game although i play other games fantasy etc